# ¿Puedo hacer un "pagination" customizada en backpack 4.1?

Tags: backpack-for-laravel

**Introducción**: Estoy intentando hacer una paginación customizada en mi panel de backpack donde tengo una tabla: [image: tabla_productos] que tiene muchos productos (llega a tener más de 300 páginas). No quiero que el usuario tenga que ir de una en una si por ejemplo quiere ir directamente a la pagina 290, por ello quería hacer un mini buscador al lado de la paginación donde poniendo en número de la página que quieras ir, pues al pulsar "Enter" te mande allí. Aquí dejo una imagen gráfica editada por mi:

[image: idea_paginacion]

**¿Que he hecho hasta ahora?**: He revisado la documentación de backpack 4.1, pero no hay nada sobre crear una paginación personalizada. Por ahora lo que llevo es que he sobreescrito los archivos "list.blade.php" y "datatables_logic.blade.php", y aquí es donde estoy atascado. No se que tengo que editar u que parte del código se relaciona con la paginación...